# Viewing the image before upload not working in IE

Tags: javascript, html, image, file-upload

I choose an image from the window that open up by clicking a button. Then I display the selected image. I am creating a div, then I create an image element. I get the source of the image from the uploaded file source and then append it in the div. It works fine without any server, But the window prompts for blocked contents and I allow it. But when i run it on the server, the image doesn't show up! Even no permission is asked! Everything works fine in chrome and firefox!

Here is some code,

```
if(document.all) {
        var image = document.createElement("img");
        image.src = document.getElementById('fileElem').value;
        }
thumbnail.appendChild(image);
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? IE doesn't support the HTML5 File API so I don't know what do you expect this code to do.

Comment: What I have seen is that server can't get the image from the src that is in the user's PC. As, there is no permission for that and neither should be!!! So, is there any way to display an image before uploading, in IE. Also, IE doesn't support filereader!

Comment: No, there's no way. You will need to upload the image to the server first and then generate a preview. Or use some client scripting technology such as Flash.

Comment: I have used file API for firefox and chrome. And it is working perfectly. But how can i do the same functionality in IE?

Comment: You can't. IE doesn't support it. That's like asking how to make a 20 years old car run with 200mph. I told you: upload the image to the server and then generate a preview or maybe some client scripting such as Flash and ActiveX. Yet another possibility is to tell your customers to use a modern browser if they want to have this instant image preview functionality of your site. But don't worry, not all hopes are lost, you will be able to do this in IE 10.

Comment: I know it is possible in IE10. But I want the functionality to work in IE8,9 too. And I don't want to use the flash!!!

Comment: OK, then upload the image to the server and generate the preview over there. And please stop asking me how to make a 20 years old car run with 200mph. I told you I don't know the answer :-)

Comment: I'm not specifically asking you! I'm asking everyone! Maybe someone is so passionate and intelligent to make a 20 years old car run with 200mph. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would have worked in older browsers because traditionally `<input type="file" />` had a `value` attribute that returned the full path to the specified file in the local filesystem. However since around 2006 (think IE7+, Firefox 2+, Chrome, etc) browsers no longer provide the full file path, they only provide the file's name without directory information. This is to protect the user's privacy (because uploaded "My Documents" files might contain the user's real-life name, for example).

This affects both uploaded files (the browser no-longer sends the full file path in POST requests, so server-side code only get the filename and file data) as well as local scripts (as you're experiencing yourself).

Comment: But I'm getting the full filepath of the image using image.src = document.getElementById('fileElem').value;

Comment: It depends on the browser. Also some browsers might have different rules. Also, are you adding the "file://" URI scheme prefix?

Comment: Yes. But there is no solution for IE. I have to upload it on server and then getting it and draw it!